# Uploading an attachment to Azure DevOps Server using Rest API from a JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-devops, binaryfiles

I'm looking for an example on how to generate the request body when uploading an attachment to Azure DevOps Server. Looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#upload-a-binary-file), it notes the content for the body should be "[BINARY FILE CONTENT]". The content of the body is coming from a URL (https://someURL/images/abc.png for example). How do I get from fetch(url) -> binary content to put in the POST request to create the attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works. For reference here's the code:

```
        //Get the stream from the content URL
        getStreamData(screenshot.src).then(function (streamData) {

            //Get the blob data from the stream
            streamData.blob().then(function (blob) {

                //upload the attachment 
                uploadAttachment(blob, fileName).then(function (res) {
                    console.log("Attachment uploaded successfully: ", res);

                    //Update work item with attachment link
                    linkAttachmentToWorkitem(res.url, <workItemID>);
                });
            });
        });
```

The key to all of this, for me anyway, was adding

```
processData: false
```

to the ajax settings, for the POST request, in the uploadAttachment function.